# How Can i cover the below code in test class

Tags: unit-test, controller, scheduled-apex

```
 public Pagereference CancelRec() {
        GS_Mass_Debrief__c headerrec = [Select id,name from GS_Mass_Debrief__c where Name =:Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get ('Name') limit 1];
        PageReference headerPage = new PageReference ('/'+headerrec.Id);
                   return headerPage ;
```

---

```
PageReference tpageRef = Page.GS_EditGroupedWorkorders;
    tpageRef.getParameters().put('id', workOrderlist[0].Id);
    Test.setCurrentPage(tpageRef);

    System.assertEquals(Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get ('Id'),workOrder1.id);
    Test.stopTest();

    ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(md);
    GS_EditGroupedWorkordersController gs = new GS_EditGroupedWorkordersController(controller);
    gs.CancelRec();
```

---

I m getting an error :

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Can someone help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class, you're looking for a Name, but in your test class, you're setting an Id. You'll need to change one or the other to match. Since I don't know how your class is used, it's likely you probably want to change the unit test to retrieve the work order name, and set the Name parameter.

Comment: I have tried passing name also,the same error repeats

Comment: @swethaa You need to query the record back from the database, since the name is apparently auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
But make sure you have added the WorkOrder and GS_Mass_Debrief__c  record which is having the same name.

```
// You have added WorkOrder records and GS_Mass_Debrief__c records too 
//before reaching to this statement 
// GS_Mass_Debrief__c record name should match the WorkOrder record name as 
// well and I think WorkOrder name is AutoNumber field
PageReference tpageRef = Page.GS_EditGroupedWorkorders;
tpageRef.getParameters().put('id', workOrderlist[0].Id);
tpageRef.getParameters().put('Name', workOrderlist[0].Name);
Test.setCurrentPage(tpageRef);

System.assertEquals(Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get ('Id'), workOrder1.id);


ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(md);
GS_EditGroupedWorkordersController gs = new GS_EditGroupedWorkordersController(controller);
gs.CancelRec();
```